# Not able to update the desired field in the form

Tags: python, django

So when I'm clicking the `edit` button I'm getting a pre-populated form. I tried to update one of my entries but i wasn't successful.

This is my `update` view:

```
def update(request, id):
    item = get_object_or_404(BookEntry, id=id)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = UpdateForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('bms:index'), id)
        else:
            form=UpdateForm(instance=item)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('bms:index'), id)
        return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

This is my `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from bms.models import BookEntry


    class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        author = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        edition = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        publisher = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        genre = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        detail = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        language = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        price = forms.IntegerField()
        dop = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        cop = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        copyright = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        isbn = forms.IntegerField()

        class Meta:
            model = BookEntry
            fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: your `update view` seems to have indentation problems, otherwise your code isn't correct

Comment: can you show the html?